# global pointer to dialog class

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I need an example that shows a global pointer to a MFC Dialog called `Dlg1`. It is initialized and is available for other dialogs to access and use it. I realize the use of global pointers have its risks and can be indicative of a design flow.

Comment: Declaring a global pointer can't be *that* difficult, so I really don't know what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

And what is your question?

See for example how Microsoft allows access to [CWinThread::m_pMainWnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3ddxzww%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). They made it a public variable

Comment: Don't know what happened. Just a tiny mistake. Now, it works.